# JavaFX Ultra HD (4K) video

Tags: javafx, java-8

I wanted to play an Ultra HD (4K) Video with JavaFX 2 MediaPlayer but do only get a black screen (run on JRE 8/Windows 7). There are no error messages.

Does anyone know if JavaFX can play Ultra HD (4K) videos or where I can find these information?

Thank you.

Comment: If it turns out to be an issue with JavaFX itself, maybe file a bug [here](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com)

Comment: Ensure that you have full JavaFX media error handling code implemented as per the [JavaFX media javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html). Update your question to include any error information you find.  Verify that the video you are playing is a supported format as per the javadoc link and that your system meets [minimum specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html). Still have errors? -> log a bug report.

Comment: I've applied the error handling. Now I see an error message: ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID on object com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer. So unfortunatelly the player does not support ultra hd

Comment: There is an existing bug report regarding this for Java 8 on OS X and Windows: [JDK-8091277: JavaFx MediaPlayer unable to Play 4K ultra HD (3840 x 2160) video file](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091277)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the player doesn't support anything higher than 1920 pixels wide.

I created a video this weekend with X pixels of 1980 and it couldn't play.  I figured out last night to drop it down to 1920 to make the video play.

The Y pixels can be above 1080, not sure how far above you can go, but I was at around 1100 with an X of 1800 and it still played.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm this for the Mac (with 8u60 ea). On my MacBook Pro Retina a 4K video does play, but the screen is somehow split in the middle and the right half of the video has the wrong colors.